# Changing width of an input element using jQuery 1.7.2 vs 1.8.0+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

There a difference in size when trying to change the width of an HTML input element when using jQuery 1.7.2 vs jQuery 1.8.0+.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
<title>Width</title>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="letter-container">
        <input type="button" value="+" class="add" id="btn"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="change" value="Change"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#change").click(function()
    {
        var width = 50;
        $('#letter-container input').width(width).height(width);//.css('line-height', (width) + 'px');
        alert($("#btn").width());
    });    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use 1.8.0+, `alert($("#btn").width())` shows 50, but FireBug shows width:56px, height:68px.
If I use 1.7.2 `alert($("#btn").width())` shows 32, but FireBug shows width:50px, height:50px.
Why such a difference ? I want to use the latest version of jQuery and want what 1.7.2 does. It looks like its the right one.
This is how 1.8.0+ shows : 
[image]

Comment: The latest version of jQuery is 1.11.2 (includes support for older version of IE) as well as 2.1.3 (which removes support for older IE)

Comment: @Travis : I'm trying to update a webpage of mine which is using 1.7.2 to 2.1.3 but cannot simply because the widths are changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because it does not include padding/border. Have a look at [outer width](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) which includes padding and a border.

In addition, from jQuery 1.8 it has the understanding of box sizing.

See here:
http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/